# How filter list of items depends on another list

Tags: javascript

I have an array of scripts "list" and an array of selected users "users",
each user can have several such scripts.

How to filter an array of "list" scripts to leave only those scripts for the correct statement in it:

- If at least someone from the list of users does not have a script from the list "list",
   we show this script
- if all users have such a script, we do not show it

Example

```
let list = [{name: 'script1', id:'1'}, {name: 'script2',id:'2'},{name: 'script3',id:'3'}]

let users = [
{name: 'user1', scripts:[{name: 'script1',id:'1'}]},
{name: 'user2', scripts:[{name: 'script1',id:'1'},{name: 'script2',id:'2'}]}
]

let result = list.filter(...)  //=> let list = [{name: 'script2'},{name: 'script3'}]
```

My try looks bad

```
let result = list.filter(item => {
      return  users.filter(user => {
        return user.scripts.some(el => {
          return el.id !== item.id
        })
      })
    })
```

Comment: There are no `salesPersonId` or `id` properties in any of the objects.

Comment: I think your two criteria are equivalent.

Comment: You have to use `! every(===)` not `some(!==)`

Comment: Yes, there is id id every object

Comment: But no `salesPersonId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making the common mistake of looking for something not equal to the search item, when you want to find an array that's missing the search item entirely. They're not equivalent, because even if one element doesn't equal the search item, some other element might.

Use `!users.every(...)` to check for something that's missing from at least one user.

```js
let list = [{name: 'script1', id:'1'}, {name: 'script2',id:'2'},{name: 'script3',id:'3'}]

let users = [
  {name: 'user1', scripts:[{name: 'script1',id:'1'}]},
  {name: 'user2', scripts:[{name: 'script1',id:'1'},{name: 'script2',id:'2'}]}
]

let result = list.filter(({id}) =>
  !users.every(({scripts}) => scripts.some(s => s.id == id)));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Good point. In this context they're equivalent, since any returned object is truthy.

Answer (score 1):

1. Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on `users` array, create a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with the `key` as the script `id` and the `value` as the number of `users` having it
2. Using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on `list` array, get the `scripts` that are not used by all `users`, then, if you want to only return the objects with the `name` use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const list = [
  { name: 'script1', id:'1' }, 
  { name: 'script2', id:'2' },
  { name: 'script3', id:'3' }
];
const users = [
  { name: 'user1', scripts:[ { name: 'script1', id:'1' } ] },
  { name: 'user2', scripts:[ { name: 'script1', id:'1' }, { name: 'script2', id:'2' } ] }
];
const TOTAL = users.length;

const usage = users.reduce((scriptUsagesMap, { scripts=[] }) => {
  scripts.forEach(({ id }) => {
    const count = scriptUsagesMap.get(id) || 0;
    scriptUsagesMap.set(id, count + 1);
  });
  return scriptUsagesMap;
}, new Map);

const result = list
  .filter(({ id }) => usage.get(id) !== TOTAL)
  .map(({ name }) => ({ name }));

console.log(result);
```